# Append and hash two Strings as Hex with sha256 in Dart(Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, sha256

I have this function in JavaScript and I want to have the same functionality in my Flutter App, but I can't find something similar:

```
const {createHash} = require("crypto")

const secret = "<SomeSecretHexNumbers>"
let id = 123456789
let idHex = id.toString(16)

if (idHex.length % 2 != 0) {
    idHex = "0" + idHex
}

let hash = createHash("sha256")
hash.update(Buffer.from(idHex, "hex"))
hash.update(Buffer.from(secret, "hex"))

const expectedHash = hash.digest("hex")

console.log("Hash: " + expectedHash)
```

I tried to do this in Dart but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this but I honestly have no idea what I'm doing:
```
var secretHex = "<Secret>";
    var secret = crypto.Hmac(
      crypto.sha256,
      utf8.encode(id),
    ).convert(utf8.encode(secretHex)).toString();
```

Comment: Why would you be using HMAC when you just want a hash?

Comment: because I have no idea about hashing and found a funny named function that allowed to values for hasing instead of just one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart's hex codex is in `package:convert` (not to be confused with `dart:convert`). As you have the sample code, you should just work through each line seeing what it does, creating the same in Dart and test side by side.

Documentation for the `sha256` digest is in the front page of the `crypto` package, with example for hashing more than one byte array.

For example:

```
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

void main() {
  const secret = 'cafe1234';
  final id = 123456789;
  final idHex = id.toRadixString(16);

  final u1 = hex.decode(idHex.padLeft((idHex.length + 1) ~/ 2 * 2, '0'));
  final u2 = hex.decode(secret);

  final output = AccumulatorSink<Digest>();
  sha256.startChunkedConversion(output)
    ..add(u1)
    ..add(u2)
    ..close();
  final expectedHash = hex.encode(output.events.single.bytes);

  print(expectedHash);
}
```

Comment: Thank's! That's excactly what I wanted!

Comment: Equally, you could convert the two values to hex (the secret is already in hex), append the two hex strings with `+` then decode to bytes and you only need `sha256.convert()` avoiding the chunked conversion.